# Crontab Error Emails: Set Sender to Root Using -f

Tags: email, authentication, crontab

For a crontab entry in this format,

```
*/1 * * * *  /usr/bin/php /app/<userid>/command --flag='value'
```

I see this message emailed to `<userid>@host` (and view via `mail`) at one per minute:

```
From root@host  Wed May  2 16:36:02 2012
Return-Path: <root@host>
Date: Wed, 2 May 2012 16:36:01 -0400
X-Authentication-Warning: host: <userid> set sender to root using -f
From: root@host (Cron Daemon)
To: <userid>@host
Subject: Cron <<userid>@host> /usr/bin/php /app/<userid>/command --flag='value'
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/bash>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/<userid>/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/<userid>>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=<userid>>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=<userid>>
Status: R
```

I'm unsure what this error is, particularly the 4th line and if it something to be worried about. This only happens on one of our test servers, and the production servers are fine. I don't have root access on these servers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
X-Authentication-Warning: host: <userid> set sender to root using -f
```

That line is something I've seen sendmail do.  It is a common result of sending mail via something like:

```
blahblahblah.sh | /usr/sbin/sendmail  -f $SENDER $RECIPIENT
```

Where `$SENDER` is 'root' (and sender masquerade isn't on.)

I wouldn't consider it something to worry about, it's just letting the recipient know that the sender was manually forced and could be bogus.

In any event, I don't imagine that that's the cause of cron emailing you -- that's a result of the emailing process.  Was there any further content to the message?  Also, does `Status: R` mean anything to you? Because it's not an email header field I recognize.

Comment: Turns out there was a typo between the test and prod servers, which was reconciled, see my comment to Antony's answer below. I'm afraid I don't recall it, but thank you for your insights.

Answer (score 1):

Could be email message that is bounced / returned  because it could not be delivered

see reference
http://docs.phplist.com/PhpListConfigBounces.html

Comment: Thanks for weighing in Antony, it *is* delivered, as I can view/read it using `mail`. Turns out, there was a typo in one of the scripts that is called by the crontab script, and fixing the former has resolved this issue.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :D